# Python: Working with XML files non-intrusively

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, minidom

I have a large number of XML file in which I want to make the following changes:

1. Create a new element – let's call it `new_element` – under the root element
2. Find another, specific element, which is more deeply nested – let's call it `existing_element` – and move it such that it becomes a child of `new_element`

I want to do this in the least intrusive way possible, such that the diff between the old file and the new file only shows changes on rows that either belong to the newly created element (and hence have been added to the file) or that used to belong to the element that was moved (and hence have been removed from the file). I want to do this using Python 3.

However, when I try just reading one of the XML files with `xml.dom.minidom` and writing what I just read to a new file and diff the two files, every single line gets marked as changed (probably because they contain different types newlines). Besides, when I look at the contents of the two files, I see that the encoding specification in the XML declaration, as well as the newline after the declaration, have disappeared, and attributes in tags all throughout the document have had their order shuffled within the tag.

The story is very similar when using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, only that now the entire XML declaration disappears, all tag names are preceded by "`ns0:`" (for some reason), and some attribute names are followed by "`:ns0`".

None of these "extra" modifications to the XML files are desirable, since I want to be able to diff the old file and the new file and be able to easily see what has changed and what has not.

**So**, is there some simple way to create a new XML file based on another XML file that only introduces changes to lines that really are supposed to be changed and leave all other lines untouched, and that doesn't involve writing your own code to parse the XML data?

**Edit:** Here is the structure of the file I want to process (since I don't know what will cause any suggested code to work or not to work with my XML files, I have only removed the data stored on three different places in the file – which I have replaced with "`*data*`" – and kept everything else exactly as it is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <contributor/>
        <created>2017-01-23T12:01:30Z</created>
        <modified>2017-01-23T12:01:30Z</modified>
        <unit/>
        <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>
    <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="defaultScene">
            <node id="sceneRoot">
                <instance_geometry url="#geometry">
                    <bind_material>
                        <technique_common>
                            <instance_material symbol="geometry_material" target="#material">
                                <bind_vertex_input semantic="texcoord0" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" input_set="0"/>
                            </instance_material>
                        </technique_common>
                    </bind_material>
                </instance_geometry>
            </node>
        </visual_scene>
    </library_visual_scenes>
    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="geometry">
            <mesh>
                <source id="geometry-positions">
                    <float_array id="geometry-positions-array" count="673731">*data*</float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="224577" source="#geometry-positions-array" stride="3">
                            <param name="X" type="float"/>
                            <param name="Y" type="float"/>
                            <param name="Z" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <source id="geometry-texcoord_0">
                    <float_array id="geometry-texcoord_0-array" count="449154">*data*</float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="224577" source="#geometry-texcoord_0-array" stride="2">
                            <param name="S" type="float"/>
                            <param name="T" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <vertices id="geometry-vertices">
                    <input semantic="POSITION" source="#geometry-positions"/>
                </vertices>
                <triangles count="329753" material="geometry_material">
                    <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#geometry-vertices" set="0"/>
                    <input offset="1" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#geometry-texcoord_0" set="0"/>
                    <p>*data*</p>
                </triangles>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>
    <library_materials>
        <material id="material">
            <instance_effect url="#material_effect"/>
        </material>
    </library_materials>
    <library_effects>
        <effect id="material_effect">
            <profile_COMMON>
                <image id="material_effect-image" height="0" width="0">
                    <init_from>Tile_+037_+047_0.jpg</init_from>
                </image>
                <newparam sid="material_effect-surface">
                    <surface type="2D">
                        <init_from>material_effect-image</init_from>
                    </surface>
                </newparam>
                <newparam sid="material_effect-sampler">
                    <sampler2D>
                        <source>material_effect-surface</source>
                        <wrap_s>CLAMP</wrap_s>
                        <wrap_t>CLAMP</wrap_t>
                        <minfilter>LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR</minfilter>
                        <magfilter>LINEAR</magfilter>
                        <border_color>0 0 0 0</border_color>
                    </sampler2D>
                </newparam>
                <technique sid="t0">
                    <phong>
                        <emission>
                            <color>0 0 0 1</color>
                        </emission>
                        <ambient>
                            <color>1 1 1 1</color>
                        </ambient>
                        <diffuse>
                            <texture texture="material_effect-sampler" texcoord="texcoord0">
                                <extra type="color">
                                    <technique profile="SCEI">
                                        <color>1 1 1 1</color>
                                    </technique>
                                </extra>
                            </texture>
                        </diffuse>
                        <specular>
                            <color>0 0 0 1</color>
                        </specular>
                        <shininess>
                            <float>0</float>
                        </shininess>
                    </phong>
                </technique>
            </profile_COMMON>
        </effect>
    </library_effects>
    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#defaultScene"/>
    </scene>
</COLLADA>
```

This is what I want the XML to turn into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
    <asset>
        <contributor/>
        <created>2017-01-23T12:01:30Z</created>
        <modified>2017-01-23T12:01:30Z</modified>
        <unit/>
        <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
    </asset>
    <library_visual_scenes>
        <visual_scene id="defaultScene">
            <node id="sceneRoot">
                <instance_geometry url="#geometry">
                    <bind_material>
                        <technique_common>
                            <instance_material symbol="geometry_material" target="#material">
                                <bind_vertex_input semantic="texcoord0" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" input_set="0"/>
                            </instance_material>
                        </technique_common>
                    </bind_material>
                </instance_geometry>
            </node>
        </visual_scene>
    </library_visual_scenes>
    <library_geometries>
        <geometry id="geometry">
            <mesh>
                <source id="geometry-positions">
                    <float_array id="geometry-positions-array" count="673731">*data*</float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="224577" source="#geometry-positions-array" stride="3">
                            <param name="X" type="float"/>
                            <param name="Y" type="float"/>
                            <param name="Z" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <source id="geometry-texcoord_0">
                    <float_array id="geometry-texcoord_0-array" count="449154">*data*</float_array>
                    <technique_common>
                        <accessor count="224577" source="#geometry-texcoord_0-array" stride="2">
                            <param name="S" type="float"/>
                            <param name="T" type="float"/>
                        </accessor>
                    </technique_common>
                </source>
                <vertices id="geometry-vertices">
                    <input semantic="POSITION" source="#geometry-positions"/>
                </vertices>
                <triangles count="329753" material="geometry_material">
                    <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#geometry-vertices" set="0"/>
                    <input offset="1" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#geometry-texcoord_0" set="0"/>
                    <p>*data*</p>
                </triangles>
            </mesh>
        </geometry>
    </library_geometries>
    <library_materials>
        <material id="material">
            <instance_effect url="#material_effect"/>
        </material>
    </library_materials>
    <library_effects>
        <effect id="material_effect">
            <profile_COMMON>
                <newparam sid="material_effect-surface">
                    <surface type="2D">
                        <init_from>material_effect-image</init_from>
                    </surface>
                </newparam>
                <newparam sid="material_effect-sampler">
                    <sampler2D>
                        <source>material_effect-surface</source>
                        <wrap_s>CLAMP</wrap_s>
                        <wrap_t>CLAMP</wrap_t>
                        <minfilter>LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR</minfilter>
                        <magfilter>LINEAR</magfilter>
                        <border_color>0 0 0 0</border_color>
                    </sampler2D>
                </newparam>
                <technique sid="t0">
                    <phong>
                        <emission>
                            <color>0 0 0 1</color>
                        </emission>
                        <ambient>
                            <color>1 1 1 1</color>
                        </ambient>
                        <diffuse>
                            <texture texture="material_effect-sampler" texcoord="texcoord0">
                                <extra type="color">
                                    <technique profile="SCEI">
                                        <color>1 1 1 1</color>
                                    </technique>
                                </extra>
                            </texture>
                        </diffuse>
                        <specular>
                            <color>0 0 0 1</color>
                        </specular>
                        <shininess>
                            <float>0</float>
                        </shininess>
                    </phong>
                </technique>
            </profile_COMMON>
        </effect>
    </library_effects>
    <scene>
        <instance_visual_scene url="#defaultScene"/>
    </scene>
    <library_images>
        <image id="material_effect-image" height="0" width="0">
            <init_from>Tile_+037_+047_0.jpg</init_from>
        </image>
    </library_images>
</COLLADA>
```

Note how in the second piece of XML, a tag named `library_images` has been created under the root element (where under the root element is not important, as long as it is a direct child of it), and the element `image` has been moved into it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way called [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files from one structure to another or other formats including HTML, TXT/CSV, even JSON. Python's third-party module, `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts (not built-in `minidom` or `etree` modules). However, other languages (Java, C#, PHP, VB) and softwares (Saxon, Xalan, libxslt, .NET) can also run such scripts even [2.0 and 3.0 scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info). And Python can connect to these external solutions via command line calls.

Specifically, run the Identity Transform to preserve original format as is and then apply your needed changes to specific nodes. One challenge is handling of the default namespace requiring the definition of a prefix, *doc*, and `namespace` when creating new element, *library-images*:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ADD <new_element> AS CHILD TOO ROOT  -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:element name="library-images" namespace="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema">
                <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::doc:profile_COMMON/doc:image"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- REMOVE NODE IN DOCUMENT -->
    <xsl:template match="doc:profile_COMMON/doc:image"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('my_file.xml')
xsl = et.parse('my_script.xsl')

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    

# RUN TRANSFORMATION WITH PARAMS
result = transform(doc)

# PRINT RESULT
print(result)  

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(result)
```

**Output**

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQn/2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLADA xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema" version="1.4.1">
  <asset>
    <contributor/>
    <created>2017-01-23T12:01:30Z</created>
    <modified>2017-01-23T12:01:30Z</modified>
    <unit/>
    <up_axis>Z_UP</up_axis>
  </asset>
  <library_visual_scenes>
    <visual_scene id="defaultScene">
      <node id="sceneRoot">
        <instance_geometry url="#geometry">
          <bind_material>
            <technique_common>
              <instance_material symbol="geometry_material" target="#material">
                <bind_vertex_input semantic="texcoord0" input_semantic="TEXCOORD" input_set="0"/>
              </instance_material>
            </technique_common>
          </bind_material>
        </instance_geometry>
      </node>
    </visual_scene>
  </library_visual_scenes>
  <library_geometries>
    <geometry id="geometry">
      <mesh>
        <source id="geometry-positions">
          <float_array id="geometry-positions-array" count="673731">*data*</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor count="224577" source="#geometry-positions-array" stride="3">
              <param name="X" type="float"/>
              <param name="Y" type="float"/>
              <param name="Z" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <source id="geometry-texcoord_0">
          <float_array id="geometry-texcoord_0-array" count="449154">*data*</float_array>
          <technique_common>
            <accessor count="224577" source="#geometry-texcoord_0-array" stride="2">
              <param name="S" type="float"/>
              <param name="T" type="float"/>
            </accessor>
          </technique_common>
        </source>
        <vertices id="geometry-vertices">
          <input semantic="POSITION" source="#geometry-positions"/>
        </vertices>
        <triangles count="329753" material="geometry_material">
          <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#geometry-vertices" set="0"/>
          <input offset="1" semantic="TEXCOORD" source="#geometry-texcoord_0" set="0"/>
          <p>*data*</p>
        </triangles>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
  </library_geometries>
  <library_materials>
    <material id="material">
      <instance_effect url="#material_effect"/>
    </material>
  </library_materials>
  <library_effects>
    <effect id="material_effect">
      <profile_COMMON>
        <newparam sid="material_effect-surface">
          <surface type="2D">
            <init_from>material_effect-image</init_from>
          </surface>
        </newparam>
        <newparam sid="material_effect-sampler">
          <sampler2D>
            <source>material_effect-surface</source>
            <wrap_s>CLAMP</wrap_s>
            <wrap_t>CLAMP</wrap_t>
            <minfilter>LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR</minfilter>
            <magfilter>LINEAR</magfilter>
            <border_color>0 0 0 0</border_color>
          </sampler2D>
        </newparam>
        <technique sid="t0">
          <phong>
            <emission>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <ambient>
              <color>1 1 1 1</color>
            </ambient>
            <diffuse>
              <texture texture="material_effect-sampler" texcoord="texcoord0">
                <extra type="color">
                  <technique profile="SCEI">
                    <color>1 1 1 1</color>
                  </technique>
                </extra>
              </texture>
            </diffuse>
            <specular>
              <color>0 0 0 1</color>
            </specular>
            <shininess>
              <float>0</float>
            </shininess>
          </phong>
        </technique>
      </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
  </library_effects>
  <scene>
    <instance_visual_scene url="#defaultScene"/>
  </scene>
  <library-images>
    <image id="material_effect-image" height="0" width="0">
      <init_from>Tile_+037_+047_0.jpg</init_from>
    </image>
  </library-images>
</COLLADA>
```

Comment: Please see updated answer yielding desired result. Also, please delete above past comments.

Comment: Thanks, now your code works on my example! However, when I try it on a file in which the data has not been removed, I get the error message `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node, line 53, column 10001702`, triggered by the line `doc = et.parse('my_file.xml')`. Seems like XSLT is having problems with the long lines in my file. Do you know if it's possible to make XSLT handle even those lines?

Comment: That is not an XSLT issue but just a general XML parse error as original doc cannot be read in. Usually this is due to XML not being well-formed (i.e., broken tags, special chars not escaped). I never encountered that *huge text node* issue. If you can post an example that would be great as I am interested to see such a file.

Comment: I don't know how I can post an example here if the file is so large (the question would become very long), but consider replacing all three occasions of "`*data*`" with, say, 20 MB worth of actual data – I presume it doesn't matter what data you enter here as long as the XML parser sees it as text – and you have the type of file I'm dealing with.

Comment: However, I ended up using `minidom` anyway; it turned out that after converting the newlines in the generated file to match the newlines in the source file the diff wasn't that bad. It's definitely not the least intrusive way possible, but it is good enough for my needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway; this was the first time I heard about XSL and XSLT!